# How Can I Share Live Locations in My App without need for Installation

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, location, share

I'm working on an flutter app with live tracking. I want users to share a link with their friends that shows their live location through messaging apps. Clicking on the link should open Google Maps without needing to install the same app.

I've set up Firebase for real-time location storage, but I'm not sure how to create a link to send this live location.
Any ideas on how to tackle this? Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Get the `latitude`, `longitude` value from you `Firestore` database and you could create a shareable link in `String` format in below format from Flutter and share.
You may share the created link via [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) Flutter Plugin.

```
String latitude = '52.589090';
String longitude = '68.299377';
String sharebableLink = "https://maps.google.com/?q=$latitude,$longitude"
```

Anyone receives this link can directly open it in Google Map without the need of any other App.

Hope this helps.